# Logical URL query-parameter language

Tags: api, rest

I'm creating a REST API which can handle a dynamic set of filters (send as queryparams). In some cases the client wants to have a combination of filter applicable for a collection list. This could be nested and combined with AND/OR.

**I wonder if there is any standard or opensource language definition for these statements which is specialised for use as URL query-parameters.**

Comment: Odata has some convetions. See http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html

Comment: Afaik there are no standards just conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Google I've decided to do it like this:

By default, multiple queryparams are logical ANDed together. Any bundled values are considered OR.
e.g.

GET /users?filter=field1:value1,value2,value2&filter=fieldFoo=bar

Answer (score -1):

The below one is the simplest way for doing this.

GET /users?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3

It is easily understood and easy to use.

Comment: Would this take care of logically pairing?